Format a cell within a nested table in Microsoft word
I have been trying to understand Microsoft Word VBA code. I am pretty good at Excel VBA but just now looking at Word code. The issue I have is that I have tables within tables. The data and the number of tables will vary depending on how much data I have for that day.
I need to go through each nested table and format a particular cell to be color coded based on the text in that cell. For example, if the cell data is “Ea” then color the cell with a green background, if it is “Pk” then color it yellow, ect. Depending on the color I may have to also change the text color so it can be easily read.  In Excel conditional formatting would be my go-to option but Word is not that easy.
I looked at changing the table name as seen in the code, to see if that would help but it did not.
Using some of the code I got from the helpful team here I was able to get Word to cycle through each nested table. But after trying many different codes I cannot get the If statement to work. The debug error "type mismatch" message keeps coming up at the ".Cell" portion of the code.
I am sure there is something simple that I am missing in the code.
Sub Test_4()

    Dim mainTable As Word.Table
    Dim nestedTable1 As Word.Table
    Dim nestedTable2 As Word.Table
    Dim n As Long
    Dim ns As Long
    Dim ns2 As Long
    Dim NumOfTbl As Long
    Dim C As Cell
    Dim Table_Name As String


    For Each mainTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    Table_Name = ""
    n = n + 1
    NumOfTbl = NumOfTbl + 1
    'Debug.Print “——; Table; ” & n & ”; ——”

    'nested level 1
    ns = 0
    For Each nestedTable1 In mainTable.Tables
    nestedTable1.Select
    ns = ns + 1
    NumOfTbl = NumOfTbl + 1


    MsgBox "Nested; Table; " & n & "." & ns
    Table_Name = n & "." & ns
    nestedTable1.Title = Table_Name

        If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(Table_Name).Range.Tables(1).Cell(4, 4) = "Ea" Then
                   ' Change Cell color to Green
                   Else
                        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(Table_Name).Range.Tables(1).Cell(4, 4) = "Pk"
                        'Change Cell color to Yellow
                    
        End If

    Table_Name = ""
    Next nestedTable1
    Next mainTable

    MsgBox "Total number of Lables: " & NumOfTbl - 1

End Sub


The Type Mismatch is because you are trying to compare a Table Cell ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(Table_Name).Range.Tables(1).Cell(4, 4) to a String "Ea" and those two 'types' are not comparable.
I guess the compare you actually want to do is that of the text within the Table Cell to the String which would be
If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(Table_Name).Range.Tables(1).Cell(4, 4).Range.Text = "Ea" Then

However, that ignores the fact that the text within every Table Cell always ends with the 'end of Cell' characters (13 and 7) and so the code you would want to use would remove those characters, for which we can use VBA's Replace function:
If Replace(ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(Table_Name).Range.Tables(1).Cell(4, 4).Range.Text, Chr$(13) & Chr$(7), vbNullString) = "Ea" Then

... this fixes the first .Cell problem in your code and you will need to do likewise for the second problem on the later line.

Thanks this helped me out a lot. The only other issue I found was I did not specifically name the bookmark in my code. I assumed the table title was the same thing. Once I corrected that error, the code words.
Thanks once again!
